# Flexbox Justify Content Space Between items are not evenly distributed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this navbar with flexbox. I use `justify-content: space-between` but it seems the items are not evenly distribute as the center item is a bit on the left side. Is there something i am missing? Sorry for the basic question.

[How it currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GpFP.png) and [how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAH2f.png)

Codepen: https://codepen.io/joxs546/pen/qBRYZLa

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #e2dfe3;
}

.logo {
  height: 85px;
  width: 85px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: url('https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.logo:hover {
  background: url('https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/ffff') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

li,
a,
button {
  font-family: PT Sans, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10%;
}

.nav-ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-ul li {
  padding: 0px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-ul li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav-ul li a:hover {
  color: cornflowerblue;
}

button {
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

button:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="logo">
  </div>
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="nav-ul">
      <li> <a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">Project</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <a class="nav-button" href="#"></a><button>Contact</button>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `<button>Contact</button>` inside of `<a>` tag.
Also you can use `justify-content: space-evenly;` in case you want to fill the space evenly.

Answer (score 2):

There is an empty `a` tag that is taking some space. Either it should be removed from the HTML or it should wrap the `button`. Everything else is perfect.

```
<a class="nav-button" href="#">
    <button>Contact</button>
</a>
```

Comment: Oh I see it now. Thanks for the help. I appreciate it a lot been trying to found out what i miss. My bad.